# How to send a message to openvpn client from management interface before killing the connection?

Tags: openvpn

I have a script that enforces simultaneous connection limits for certain users, so the server runs with a duplicate-cn option.

I have a way to manage and kill connections already, however I would like to be able to be able to distinguish at the client a forced disconnect (using the kill command in openvpn management console) from any network issues (server went down, latency, packet loss, etc).

Is there any way to push a message to a specific client before the kill command is sent to sever the connection, so it can be detected and handled appropriately?

Comment: That's a relative question with a relative answer.  It depends on the VPN client and the remote system's OS.

Comment: Im using the openvpn binary in a custom client. Why would the client OS matter?

Comment: There are options where you can script a message based off the IP of the client, and then there are VPN client specific solutions (if the VPN client can support it). But, your question is very broad, so, you're getting a very broad answer.

Comment: Clients support the "explicit-exit-notify" option which can be used to notify the server explicitly the client is about to tear its session down (and we're using it in production). I'm not sure servers support it as well but this could be a start for your research.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do the opposite. The server should notify the client that their session is about to be disconnected (by running "kill common_name" in management console).

Answer (score 0):

For versions that support "client-kill" command, you can use "client-kill CID [MSG]" and capture "WARNING: Received unknown control message: MSG" in client log.

[Related code in github](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/1000d5e1191d0a372e9e82f76dd1d1f101fe308e/src/openvpn/forward.c#L400)